# Angular route not matching with Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs, angular-routing

I am attempting to use Angular in an already existing MVC 3 site. I have gotten my primary ngApp working with the first loaded item, but as soon as I add a module and attempt to implement `$routeParams` it appears that the route provider begins to break down. In my MVC 3 application, I have a valid route `/Article/ReadArticle/key` route that allows key to be null, and I have a corresponding Controller/Action that delivers the requested article. If `key` is null or empty, then it provides the latest entered article. I have another post action that does the same thing except that it returns a `JsonResult` instead of a view.

I modified my view to exclude any MVC constructed model so the action simply returns what is essentially an html page with all of the angular templating in it. The angular controller calls the post action for the JsonResult and all is peachy. I added routing in the angular module according to the samples, but for some reason it does not appear to be catching the route:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

angular.module('je', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
      when('/Article/ReadArticle/:key', { templateUrl: '/Angular/ArticleView.html', controller: ArticleCtrl }) //.
      //otherwise({ templateUrl: '/Angular/ArticleView.html', controller: ArticleCtrl });
  } ]);
```

I commented out the `otherwise` call. If I leave that in there, it works but only to bring the default article. Manually entering a valid route such as `/Article/ReadArticle/Some_Valid_Key` does not produce any appropriate `$routeParams`. Commented out, no routes appear to match so no templates are loaded and the page is blank.

```
function ArticleCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    console.log($routeParams.key);
    $http.post("/Article/GetArticleText", { "textkey": $routeParams.key }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.article = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Request failed");
        console.log(status);
    });
}
```

According to the samples, my expectation is that `$routeParams.key` should be populated with `Some_Valid_Key` at this point. Clearly my expectations are not in line with reality, but what piece am I missing to get the route to behave?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS routes are defined after the hash of the URL.  So in your scenario, where your base URL was `/Article/ReadArticle/key`, no route is currently defined.  This is why your default route was being followed (prior to commenting out the `otherwise` line).  In order for AngularJS to follow your defined route, your URL must look something like the following: `http://mysite.com/someurl/#/Article/ReadArticle/Some_Valid_Key`.

Comment: The route worked when I took Microsoft MVC out of the equation. Adjusting the angular route to "circumvent" the MVC route only caused an MVC routing problem. There appears to be a clash between the MVC routing and the angular routing.

Comment: It seems that angular routing and viewresults are incompatible. I am starting to think that the only possible course of action is to not use viewresults but just use jsonresults. If anyone has successfully used viewresult and angularjs, please share your experiences. Thanks!

Comment: Well viewresults and viewcontrollers hardly makes much sense when you start using a JavaScript MVC, beyond a single view controller resolving to the same Index.html/aspx or what you end up calling the main file. (IMO)